# How to mock android print job?

Tags: android, mocking, automated-tests, robotium, calabash

I'm automating tests to android applications and after to execute tests I need to send job to print and get the status. In my Apk I don't have print methods implemented and i'm using native android print methods, but automated test tools like calabash doesn't identify native android methods. So I would like to use android mock methods to get this status and continue my set of tests. Does anyone have some example to mock android print methods? I'm trying automating tests using calabash and robotium tools.

Comment: Can you be more specific?  Are you talking about using the `PrintManager` to create `PrintJob`s and you're now trying to get some kind of status that the `PrintJob` was completed?  You can check if the job .isFailed, .isCanceled etc...